# SQL Full Outer Join and combining two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have the following two tables:

TableA:

```
UserID      PermissionTableA
UserA       PermissionA
UserB       PermissionA
UserC       PermissionB
UserD       PermissionB
```

TableB:

```
UserID      PermissionTableB    
UserA       PermissionC     
UserA       PermissionD     
UserB       PermissionC     
UserB       PermissionD
```

The two tables shall be joined via ID and the Permissions should be combined into one single column, like this:

Solution:

```
UserID      Permission      
UserA       PermissionC     
UserA       PermissionD     
UserA       PermissionA     
UserB       PermissionC     
UserB       PermissionD     
UserB       PermissionA
```

My current solution however, with full outer join, looks like this:

```
UserID      PermissionTableA    PermissionTableB
UserA       PermissionC         -
UserA       PermissionD         -
UserA       -                   PermissionA     
UserB       PermissionC         -
UserB       PermissionD         -
UserB       -                   PermissionA
```

Is it possible to combine both columns into one, similar to the solution table above with a SQL query (using MS Access).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think you can to use something along the lines of CASE WHEN, but not sure what the equivalent is in ms-access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for a join :-) A join combines records. What you are after is the union of two query results.

```
select UserID, PermissionTableA as Permission
from TableA
UNION 
select UserID, PermissionTableB
from TableB
where UserID in (select UserID from TableA)
order by UserID, Permission;
```

**UPDATE:** You may as well use your outer join with `NZ`. Sorry, it took me some time to see what the query was supposed to do.

```
select UserId, NZ(PermissionTableA, PermissionTableB) as Permission
from ...
```

Comment: Would that give him the desired outcome?

Comment: @Vijey: Well, except for the sort order. If that were important, one had to create sortkeys for the tables on the fly. I guessed it wasn't, so I kept my answer simple.

Comment: @Vijey: Ah, I see now what you mean. I must dismiss Users C and D. I'll edit. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was alluding to :)

Comment: I strongly prefer the `UNION` to the outer join.